# Is there a way to access an array element via multiple keys?

Tags: javascript, php, json

I'm trying to store some data in an associative array in php for access in javascript later. I want to process the data in such a way that I can access it in multiple ways, say both by name and by type?

```
//e.g. in cpp i would do
struct SortedFruits{
  std::unordered_map<std::string, Fruits> byName;
  std::unordered_map<std::string, std::unordered_map<std::string, Fruits&>> byType;
}
SortedFruit fruit();
//then add them like
fruit.byName["apple"] = new Apple();
fruit.byType["red"]["apple"] = &fruit.byName["apple"];
```

I basically just want `fruits.byType['red']['apple'] === fruits.byName['apple']` somehow. Ideally I want this to be done in php so i can store it somwhere and not recomputed, but if references/pointers can't survive inside a json I'm happy doing the sorting in javascript as well.

May I ask what's the best way to do this?

Comment: Better to just return a list of objects with relevant properties and then in the JS you could have a way to search them.

Comment: @ADyson May I ask why? Also how should I search them in JS?

Comment: Because otherwise you'd have to put the same data into multiple places in the JSON under different indexes. Which is messy. Pretty sure you can find search/filter/indexing code in JavaScript already which could search an array of objects - have a search around online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think formatting the datas in php that way to be parsed by js later from a json is not the best way to do.
Basically you have objects `Fruit` that have two properties `name` and `color`. I'd just encode a json with an array of `Fruit` and in js map it the way I want to use those objects.
I don't think mapping the objects is the responsability of the server, it's responsability is to give the client the datas.

### Edit (in response of the comment)

In JS i would even not store them in multiple maps.

```
const fruits = [
    {color: 'red', name: 'apple'},
    {color: 'red', name: 'strawberry'},
    {color: 'yellow', name: 'banana'}
];

const redOnes = fruits.filter(fruit => fruit.color === 'red');
// will return [{color: 'red', name: 'apple'}, {color: 'red', name: 'strawberry'}]

const apple = fruits.find(fruit => fruit.name === 'apple');
// will return {color: 'red', name: 'apple'}
```

Comment: I just thought doing so server side makes the page faster since the processed list can be stored in a file or a cache somewhere?
Regardless, is there a way to sort them in js that doesn't involve storing duplicates?